# How do I Stop a Strongloop Service?

Tags: strongloop

I have two strongloop services running shown here when I check status:

```
 user-3340 ~/projects/loopback/places-api $ slc ctl -C http://IPADDRESS:8701 status
Service ID: 1
Service Name: placesAPI
Environment variables:
  No environment variables defined
Instances:
    Version  Agent version  Debugger version  Cluster size  Driver metadata
     5.1.0       2.0.2             n/a              4             N/A
Processes:
       ID      PID  WID  Listening Ports  Tracking objects?  CPU profiling?  Tracing?  Debugging?
    1.1.1112  1112   0
    1.1.1244  1244   6     0.0.0.0:3001
    1.1.2567  2567   77    0.0.0.0:3001
    1.1.5386  5386  233

Service ID: 2
Service Name: Service2
Environment variables:
  No environment variables defined
Instances:
    Version  Agent version  Debugger version  Cluster size  Driver metadata
     5.1.0       2.0.2             n/a              4             N/A
Processes:
       ID      PID  WID  Listening Ports  Tracking objects?  CPU profiling?  Tracing?  Debugging?
    2.1.1117  1117   0
    2.1.1231  1231   5
    2.1.1279  1279   6
    2.1.2576  2576   77
```

What I want to know is,  how do I disable service2?   Is there a command line command I can use to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the `remove` subcommand for `slc ctl`. Something like this:

```
slc ctl -C http://IPADDRESS:8701 remove 2
```

You can find the docs for it and other commands online at https://docs.strongloop.com/display/NODE/slc+ctl or by doing `slc ctl --help`